# Closing modal with same button

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

i use the following jquery to pop up a full screen overlay modal. My menu has a higher z-index so it always stays on top of everything. Problem is, I want to be able to close my modal with the same button that launches it. Right now it just reloads the modal. I tried to change the `$("a[rel=modal]”)` so it does `close(modalId);` , but to no avail. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6c2pe2/ , code:

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.modal = function() {
    var t = Math.floor($("body").scrollTop());
    var bg = $("<div id='modal-bg'></div>");
    $("body").append(bg);
    $("#modal-bg").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "height": "100%",
        "width": "100%",
        "z-index": 100,
        "opacity": 0
    });
    $("#modal-bg").fadeTo(200, 1);

    var modalId = $(this).attr("href");
    $(modalId).css({
        'display': 'block',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'left': (($(window).width() - $(modalId).outerWidth()) / 2),
        'top': (($(window).height() - $(modalId).outerHeight()) / 2),
        'opacity': 0,
        'z-index': 200
    });
    $(modalId).fadeTo(200, 1);
    $(window).scrollTop(t - (($(window).height() - $(modalId).outerHeight()) / 2) + 1);

    $("#modal-bg").click( function() {
        close(modalId);
    });
};

$("a[rel=modal]").click( function() {
    $(this).modal();
});

function close(id){
    $(id).css('display', 'none');
    $("#modal-bg").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout( function() {$("#modal-bg").remove();}, 200);
};

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if there's a modal in the DOM in the click event ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6c2pe2/1/

```
$("a[rel=modal]").click( function() {
    if ($("#modal-bg").length) {
        close();
    } else {
        $(this).modal();
    }
});
```

Comment: This way the background closes nicely, but the content stays visible after still. http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6c2pe2/2/